# Eigenvalues of matrix - only $1$ or $0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a matrix so $A=A^2$.

I need to show that the eigenvalues of $A$ are only $1$ or $0$.

I tried some ways but none of them help.

Comment: Write your math symbols with `$...$`.

Comment: Hint: look up idempotent matrices. Regards

Comment: In the future, if you've attempted a question, please post your attempt. That way, we can point out any mistakes you've made or suggest what to do next. I answered your question nevertheless but it was a bit of a stab in the dark!

Comment: If $A$ is not invertible, what do you know about the determinant of $A$? if $A$ is invertible, what can you do to both sides of the equation $A=A^2$? This doesn't fully answer your question, but should give you some hints to solving it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $v$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$. Then $Av=\lambda v$ and $A^2v=\lambda^2 v$. If $A^2=A$, what does this tell you about $\lambda$?

Comment: thank you! simple as that.

Comment: @user1816377 Don't forget to mark this as the correct answer.